# registerDialogClass causes a issue?

Tags: c++, win32gui

Beginner question: I'm building a standard winAPI in C++ and my code runs fine. I have built a menu file > options> info>. File works perfect, options and info are supposed to open a modal dialog.

Now I have the problem that the content of the option dialog also appears in the info dialog. I have registered a dialog class and use it for both. The info dialog should be empty (obviously). My WNDCLASS is standard, not WNDCLASSW or WNDCLASSEX (is that a problem)?

I can compile normally and the program works. I only have this issue with the double content (except in info the close button is not present)

```
void registerDialogClass(HINSTANCE hThisInstance)
{
WNDCLASSW dialog = {0};
dialog.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
dialog.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_CROSS);
dialog.hInstance = hThisInstance;
dialog.lpszClassName = L"myDialogClass";
dialog.lpfnWndProc = DialogProcedure;
RegisterClassW(&dialog);
}

void displayOptions(HWND hwnd)
{
HWND hDlg = CreateWindowW(L"myDialogClass", L"Options");
        CreateWindowW(...); //edit
        CreateWindowW(...); // edit
        CreateWindowW(...); // button
}


void displayInfo(HWND hwnd)
{
HWND hDlg = CreateWindowW(L"myDialogClass", L"Options");
}
```

Comment: It's a little unusual to register your own dialog class.  Most dialogs are created with `CreateDialog` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialoga ) and you only supply the template (for the dialog) and callback function.  Can you expand on why you need your own dialog class please?

Comment: hi richard, i am a beginner. i have seen several tutorials and i tought this is the way to do it?

Comment: We need an [mre] that compiles.  [`CreateWindowW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww) takes way more than two parameters.

Comment: this is the cpp file. http://www.randytomlinson.com/temp/example.cpp
the header file is here: http://www.randytomlinson.com/temp/define.h
and the rc here: http://www.randytomlinson.com/temp/icon.rc

Comment: Simply put `DialogBox` function in `WinMain` and nothing else except dialogbox procedure. You don't need to register class or own message loop.